# Lambda function times out calling a Step Function (or any other AWS service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have an AWS Lambda function that is supposed to call a Step Function via the aws-sdk/client-sfn package. But the function stops and times out at `await client.send( command )`.
What do I need to consider to make it work?

```
import { SFNClient, StartExecutionCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sfn";
const client = new SFNClient({region: "eu-west-1"});

export const handler = async ( event ) => {
    const d = new Date();
    const yr = d.getFullYear();
    const inputParams = {
        "uid": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
        "httpMethod": "PUT",
        "settings": 1,
        yr,
        "id": 82,
        "rd": 1
    };        
    const command = new StartExecutionCommand({
        input: JSON.stringify( inputParams ),
        name: "test",
        stateMachineArn: process.env.stateMachine
    });
    try {
        const res = await client.send( command );
        console.log( res );
        client.destroy();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    return res;
};
```

The same happens with any other AWS service I am trying to call from this Lambda function.
The IAM role has full access to all releant services:

[image]

I also set up a VPC endpoint:
[image]

The Step Function can be executed manually with no errors.

Comment: Send a different request to test the connectivity, e.g. ListActivitiesCommand. If that works then the problem may simply be a long-running request. The default Lambda function timeout is 3 seconds, which can be increased if necessary.

Comment: This isn't a permission issue, or you would be getting permission errors, not timeouts. Timeouts indicate this is a network issue. The VPC endpoint should have fixed the calls to the Step Function service, but you need to make sure the endpoint's security group allows traffic from the Lambda function's security group. You also need to ensure both DNS hostnames and DNS resolution is enabled on the VPC.

Comment: Does the connection to the AWS services work when having no VPC assigned? Is the subnet public or private? If private, do you have outbound traffic option? (NAT gateway, NAT host, ..). When not using private endpoints for the AWS services, the lambda needs to reach the public service endpoints. The lambda doesn't usually need strong permissions, like "SSM Full, VPC Full, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by allowing the VPC traffic from the Lambda function's security group.